# TIdHttpServer synchronize with VCL

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using TIdHttpServer to process some commands the problem is that some commands are beeing lost my guess is that it's from the fact that i am updating the vcl inside OnConnect.

How can i use the Synchronize method to safley update the VCL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough, just call `TThread.Synchronize()` with whatever `TThreadMethod` you want to be called by the GUI thread.  `TThreadMethod` is a parameterless `procedure of object`, but since the secondary thread making the call is blocked until after the synchronized method has been executed by the GUI thread, you can use `TThread` members in the synchronized method without any further protection.

Just for completenes, I should mention that there are several alternatives, all of which are better (even those I haven't tried because nothing could be worse).  Indy has `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` classes that you can derive from to carry variables and implement custom methods.  Newer Delphi versions have `TThread.Queue()` and `TThread.ForceQueue()` that can use anonymous methods to generate closures (with captured variables) that can be executed by the GUI thread without blocking the calling thread.  There is also the `PostMessage()` and `PostThreadMessage()` APIs - a comms system that has worked without change since D3/W95 and is sure to be available on Windows forever.

Answer (score 4):

Indy has its own `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` classes for synchronizing with the main thread in synchronous and asychronous manners, respectively.  Derive a new class from `TIdSync` and override its `DoSynchronize()` method, or derive from `TIdNotify` and override its `DoNotify()` method.

**Update:** note that these classes are largely deprecated nowadays in favor of Delphi's own static versions of the `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.(Force)Queue()` methods, which do much the same work that `TIdSync`/`TIdNotify` were originally designed for back when `TThread` still only supported a non-static `Synchronize()`.